# add class to parent li if Child element is actve

Tags: jquery, css

I have searched all over but can't seem to figure how to do this. I have a menu that has sub navigation in. I want to be able to highlight the parent `li` when the child `li` is selected. I have figured out how to get the child selected but not the parent. Please help.

Javascript

```
$('.nav a').each(function (index) {
    if (this.href.trim() == window.location) {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a id="A2" href="~/" runat="server">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.aspx">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#contact" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/products-access-control.aspx">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products-time-attendance.aspx">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products-service.aspx">Product 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/partner-solutions.aspx">Product 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="newslink1" runat="server">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.aspx">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `selected` class on `$(this)` you can also do `$(this).parent().addClass("selected")`. `parent()` can be called again and again to go up the tree (li -> ul -> li etc).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this functions in `jQuery`:

- http://api.jquery.com/parent/
- http://api.jquery.com/parents/
- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

And also for getting children:

- http://api.jquery.com/children/

---

In your example, check this:

```
$('.nav a').each(function (index) {
    if (this.href.trim() == window.location) {
        var classSelected = 'selected';

        $(this).addClass(classSelected).closest('.dropdown').addClass(classSelected);
    }
});
```

---

It's good to use chaining possibility (`$(...).foo().bar().too())` and to have string values as variables for further reuse (like `classSelected`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your structure, it appears you want to add the class to the great-grandparent of the  you are selecting:

```
$('.nav a').each(function (index) {
    if (this.href.trim() == window.location){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).parentsUntil('a').addClass("selected");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.nav a').each(function (index) {
    if (this.href.trim() == window.location)
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); //this will add selected class to
                                               //li containing the anchor tag
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.parents()` is what you looking for.

```
$('.active').parents('a').addClass('selected');
```

this get ALL parents that are li the class selected.

***jQuery Documentation :*** http://api.jquery.com/parents/

***NOTE :*** jQuery got 2 functions `parent()` and `parents()`